# Convert to CSS Selector

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Trying to convert the below given `HTML` tag of a `Image Button` which I want to click but not getting clicked while using `Xpath`.

HTML Script

```
 <img src="../../../../imagepool/transparent%21tmlservicedesk?cid=1" 
    id="reg_img_304316340" aralttxt="1" artxt="Show Application List" 
    arimgcenter="1" alt="Show Application List" title="Show Application List" 
    class="btnimg" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:23px; height:140px;">
```

Xpath Generated for the same:

```
//div[@class='btnimgdiv']/img[@id='reg_img_304316340']/@src
```

Read some of the articles that for image buttons **CSS** selector is much better than **xpath** and wanted to know how to convert the html to **CSS selector**.

[image: BMC Remedy site- need to click on the Application Image button, which i am not able to click through Xpath]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Image BUtton which i want to click but not getting clicked while using Xpath

This is because you are using `id` attribute value of the element which looks like dynamically generated.

> Read some of the articles that for image buttons CSS selector is much better than xpath

Yes, you are right, using `cssSeector` is much faster than `xpath` to locate an element.

> wanted to know how to convert the html to CSS selector.

You need to use that attribute value which is unique and unchangeable to locate element, you can use below `cssSelector` :-

```
img.btnimg[title='Show Application List']
```

---

**Reference Link** :-

- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors